# Django want to display only title

Tags: django, django-templates

Hello I have `{{order}}`In my  template. This displays all storage items. When I run the server, it shows up like this.

```
[<StorageItem: my item>, <StorageItem: Another Item>]
```

Only really want those items. I don't want it to display StorageItem or the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have, is a list of objects.
Well, you will need to iterate over the list then.
`{{ order }}` isn't really an appropriate name though, it should be {{ orders }}

```
{% for order in orders %}
  {{ order }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The brackets means its a list of items.

You can iterate:

```
{% for o in order %}
    {{ o }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or use the join filter: `{{ order|join:", " }}`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#join

As for what you want to display, I can't tell without knowing what you want!

What do you want it to display instead of StorageItem?

What's shown when you simply call `{{ o  }}` in a template is defined in your model `__unicode__` method.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

If it's  specific field, you could just type `{{ o.myfield }}`

Answer (score 1):

Then iterate through the list with `{% for %}` and display each item.